# Office 365 - Result Source to display results only from delve

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, delve

I have a requirement of displaying only delve results (only my organization results) while searching on office 365. I could not find anything relevant to this SharePoint communities. What could be the filter I need to set on Query Builder to achieve this?
I tired path:https://nam.delve.office.com but didn't help.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense when taken into context. Delve isn't a result source. It displays results based on the Microsoft Graph which pulls information from multiple locations.

You would need to query the Graph rather than creating a SharePoint search solution.

Comment: Makes sense.. I am not aware of much details on this area. Now I understood.